# Install KDevelop on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, apt, kdevelop

KDevelop has a new release 4.6  http://kdevelop.org/46/kdevelop-460-final-released

I would like to install this on Ubuntu 13.04 (or Ubuntu 13.10 if that would be easier) The proper way to install package on Ubuntu is using apt-get. So I tried :

```
sudo apt-get install kdevelop
```

Unfortunately this installs KDevelop 4.5. On the KDevelop site are a huge list of instructions. Error prone and time consuming. http://techbase.kde.org/KDevelop4/HowToCompile

Can KDevelop 4.6 be installed using apt-get? If so, how ?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 already reached EOL.

Comment: I Updated to Ubuntu 13.10 This is my Virtualbox client. My virtualbox guest addition was lost during the update. I installed the guest addition again (this time very easy). But it did not work. Virtualbox host 4.3 was requered, I had Virtualbox 4.2. The first apt-get update failed, Virtualbox was downgraded to 4.1.12, The second attempt first reading https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads and the executing

Comment: but the below answer should work.

Comment: virtual box guest additions may be in/usr/share/virtualbox.Mount the guestadditions.iso file and then run it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,you can install kdevelop 4.6 via `apt-get`,by adding the below repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kdevelop
```

Comment: I tried :   bernard@bernard-vbox2:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
sudo: unable to resolve host bernard-vbox2
[sudo] password for bernard: 
 Backports of new versions of KDE and major KDE apps for Kubuntu which are either too large a change or not yet tested enough to go to Ubuntu Backports.


 More info: https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/backports
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Comment: press enter key.

Comment: Yes !!! it works. Thank you very much Avinash. Two questions : was is happening here, and why is this not on the KDevelop site? Second how can I reward you for your good answer, I do not want to make a mistake in this.

Comment: you can reward me by accepting my answer and then if you got above 15 reputations,you can upvote any question or answer.

Comment: I am sorry my reputation is not sufficient yet. I accepted your answer. Thanks again Avinash

Comment: Installation of KDEvelop version 4.6.0 was successful. But debug (F9) is not possible. I get the message "The current launch configuration does not support the 'debug' mode." This seems to be a KDevelop bug which I reported in https://bugs.kde.org . This is an other problem (question) however. Just info for other readers who might try the above steps.